# About LinearLayout and how controls resize

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Today I have been playing a bit with the LinearLayout and have been suprised with the results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Big Text"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView2"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:text="Medium Text"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />   


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Button"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is a simple layout with a text view header, then a text view that I want it to cover all parent (but the space occupied by the bottom button) and a button that is placed at the botton side with the layout_gravity="bottom".

This produces a layout where header is shown correctly, center text view covers all remaining free space and the button does not appear. Why is this? Shouldn't the center text view just calculate its size taking into account the bottom button size?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use layout_weight="1" in your center `TextView`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this works? I have been reading about the layout_weight here at stack overflow but can't get why your solution works

Answer (score 1):

Always remember thumb rule

If you are using linear layout with vertical orientation as soon as it finds the control
with

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`

The layout will ignore all the controls present below it.

Hope this help

Vipul

Answer (score 1):

In place of  this

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

use 'wrap_content' like this

```
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"/"fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/"fill_parent"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm getting an error at this lines, I think because the "/" character.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the center text view just calculate its size taking into account the bottom button size?.

No, because you tell the second `TextView` to match its parent's height, thus `FILL_PARENT` and hence it will fill up all remaining space, leaving none for the last `TextView`.

> (...) and a button that is placed at the botton side with the layout_gravity="bottom".

Unfortunately, that's not how a `LinearLayout` works. If you set the orientation to vertical, basically only the `left` and `right` gravities will have effect. Vice versa, with the (default) horizontal orientation, only `top` and `bottom` work. The orientation determines in which direction the `View` children are dynamically positioned in order, which implies you cannot manually change the 'position' in that direction.

Now, to get the desired effect, you can give the second `TextView` a height of `0dp` and a weight of `1`, resulting in it dynamically filling up all remaining space *without* pushing the third `TextView` off the bottom. Alternatively, you can use a `RelativeLayout`, with which you *can* directly set the position, and simply instruct the middle `TextView` to sit below the first, but above the last.